# Regex to match words with first capital letter

Tags: python, regex

Trying to identify structure for my text data using a regex and hitting road blocks.

For the sample text below

> I AM A HEADER:
> Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing
> and typesetting industry.         Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's
> standard dummy text ever since the 1500s.
>
> I AM A TAB-   Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing

My below regular expression picks up 'I AM A HEADER:' and 'I AM A TAB-'

```
^\s*(?:\b[A-Z]+\b[\s]*)+(?:[:-])\s*$
```

Please suggest an edit so as to match 'I Am A Header' and 'I Am A Tab' and also
ignore the end-markers ':' and '-'.

Comment: [`^\s*(?:\b[a-zA-Z]+\b\s*)+(?=[:-])`](https://regex101.com/r/uF9zU8/2)?

Comment: `^\s*(?:(?=.+[:-]\s*$)(?:\b[A-Z][a-z]*\b[\s]*)+)` should work

Comment: Why use regex? `for myword in line.split(): if myword[0] == myword[0].upper() and myword[0].isalpha(): # do something`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use

```
^\s*(?:\b[a-zA-Z]+\b\s*)+(?=[:-])
```

See [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/uF9zU8/2)

Regex breakdown:

- `^` - start of string
- `\s*` - 0 or more whitespace
- `(?:\b[a-zA-Z]+\b\s*)+` - 1 or more sequences of

  - `\b` - word boundary (redundant)
  - `[a-zA-Z]+` - 1 or more letters
  - `\b\s*` - 0 or more whitespaces.
- `(?=[:-])` - a lookahead requiring a `:` or `-` to be right after the preceding subpattern

The main points here is adding `[a-z]` to the `[A-Z]` range, removing `\s*$` and turning `(?:...)` non-capturing group to the look-ahead (that does not consume characters).

Comment: Can I restrict the number of words that can appear before end marker ? Say from 1 to 4 words. How ?

Comment: No worries. Got it. Thanks.

Comment: Yeah, I guess by replacing `+` with `{n}` where `n` is the number. `{2}` is a  limiting quantifier matching the preceding subpattern exactly 2 times.

Answer (score 0):

Here's @stribizhev's solution which worked like charm.

```
^\s*(?:\b[a-zA-Z]+\b\s*)+(?=[:-])
```

For newbies like me this is a simple explanation of the solution:

```
> ^\s      Anchor to the white space (tab, newline, blankspace)
> *        Look for repetition of white space if any 
> (?:      Start a non-capturing group 
> \b       Look for a word 
> [a-zA-Z] Anyword that starts with either a capital or small alphabet
> +        Look for repeating capital/small alphabets
> \s*      Match a blank space after the word 
> )+       Repeat 
> (?=      Ignore what follows (my best guess) 
> [:-]     Look for ':' or '-'
```

In essence this regular expression looks for group of words in a newline followed by ':' or '-'

Make the above expression smarter by telling it beyond how many words you start loosing relevant information by adding {n, m} as

```
^[\s]*(?:\b[a-zA-Z]+\b[\s]*){1,3}(?=[:-])
```

Comment: I do not think you need the `+` after `{1,3}` since the quantifier is already greedy. Python does not support possessive quantifiers.

Comment: @stribizhev : Thanks. Edited the answer.